# Home DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system

I read something like this earlier today but I forgot where and it didnt tell me what I needed.

I want to be able to have multiple computers on my network be able to access my local lamp server. But, I do not want it to have the users access 192.168.0.53 in order to get to it but I want it to be able to get to the website through something like http://mywebpage/ instead of the ip (so that it will be easier accessible).

I know that I have to use a local recursive DNS but how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

[Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) is lightweight and simple to set up for an instance like this.  Can also be used as a DNS forwarder and DHCP server.

Answer (score 2):

You setup a local DNS server on your box and have it forward requests for everything beyond your local net to your ISP's server. Then configure boxes on your local net to use your DNS server instead of your ISP's. There a bunch of tuts out there for it, e.g.:

http://www.redhat.com/magazine/025nov06/features/dns/

Answer (score 0):

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/02/setting-dns-server-with-bind.html

check about link may help you!!

Comment: Cool. Lots of code. But, how do I use it? Do I just put it into /etc/named.conf in my server?

Comment: yes if want all your clients resolve the dns

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I have to use a local
>   recursive DNS but how do I do that?

No, you need an authoritative server for your zone.

A recursive server provide name resolution for domains which are unknown.

Comment: Actually, he'll need both because he'll need to point to a recursor that knows that 192.168.33.55 is snoopy.local.